# How can I find the longest string in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the longest string from an multidimensional array, however it is not working for some reason.

This is what I have:

```
a = 
["MAKKGKPRPDHRPPAHNPHYAHDPPPYSQQQPPLQQQNYAQQMNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"],
["MHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"], ["MTYINLGVTRTGDLMIGRHRP"],
["MRIYNRVCFQTAGCYLQNLVTTSIQPARVWTY"], ["MAACGLGRVFSAFKVDEMD"], 
["MPSGFVGKRSGFCQFCCSHI"], ["MTYSTAKEGAYPFRNFN"]]

p a.max_by{|v|v}[0]  # => "MTYSTAKEGAYPFRNFN"
```

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you create sample data, such as what is in your array, strip it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. I'd suggest using something like `[['a'], ['bb'], ['ccc']]` would be adequate.

Comment: Is there a chance that the sub-arrays will have additional elements? Or, will they *always* have a single element?

Comment: Sorry, will strip down any questions to the bare minimum in the future... The sub arrays always contain a single element - they are the result of a lookahead scan... But I have flattened it into a single array...

Comment: Yes, the flattened array is better for working with. You might want to check and see why you're getting arrays of arrays in the first place. You might be able to streamline your code to not generate those. I used to get those a lot when I was learning Ruby and wasn't using `map` correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
=> a.flatten.max_by(&:size)
=> # "MAKKGKPRPDHRPPAHNPHYAHDPPPYSQQQPPLQQQNYAQQMHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [
    ["MAKKGKPRPDHRPPAHNPHYAHDPPPYSQQQPPLQQQNYAQQMHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"],
    ["MHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"],
    ["MTYINLGVTRTGDLMIGRHRP"],
    ["MRIYNRVCFQTAGCYLQNLVTTSIQPARVWTY"],
    ["MAACGLGRVFSAFKVDEMD"],
    ["MPSGFVGKRSGFCQFCCSHI"],
    ["MTYSTAKEGAYPFRNFN"]
]
p a.max_by { |v| v[0].size }[0]
```

output:

```
"MAKKGKPRPDHRPPAHNPHYAHDPPPYSQQQPPLQQQNYAQQMHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"
```

Simply specifying `v`, comparisons are done with each element (single-element array). They are compared lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
a.max_by { |v| v.first.size }[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=> a = [["MAKKGKPRPDHRPPAHNPHYAHDPPPYSQQQPPLQQQNYAQQMHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"],
        ["MHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"],
        ["MTYINLGVTRTGDLMIGRHRP"],
        ["MRIYNRVCFQTAGCYLQNLVTTSIQPARVWTY"],
        ["MAACGLGRVFSAFKVDEMD"],
        ["MPSGFVGKRSGFCQFCCSHI"],
        ["MTYSTAKEGAYPFRNFN"]
    ]

=> a.flatten.sort_by(&:length).last

#=> "MAKKGKPRPDHRPPAHNPHYAHDPPPYSQQQPPLQQQNYAQQMHHGGGGGNRQHARPRPSPPSEVSDCVKYSLFLYNCIFWVSMHSS"
```